# Can't operate GitHub repository using SSH

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying certain git operations, such as `pull`, `push` etc but none works:
**Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

Things I have done:

1. Checked whether the remotes were ssh's: `git remote -v`

   origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)

   origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
2. Checked if the ssh agent is running: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

   Agent pid 123456
3. Added the private key to ssh agent: `ssh-add "path_to_private_key_file"`

   Identity added: "path_to_private_key_file" (email@provider.com)
4. Added the public key to Github at "https://github.com/settings/ssh/new"
5. Checked whether ssh connection is working: `ssh -T git@github.com`

   Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

[image]

Comment: Well, does the user that key belongs to have access to the repository? Are you absolutely sure the repository URL is correct?

Comment: Yes, the user (me) does have access to the repository. I just needed to change from HTTPS to SSH and yes, the URL is correct: I copied it from the repository clone popup (no manual typing).

Comment: *I just needed to change from HTTPS to SSH ...* Does this mean that it's all working now?

Comment: @torek nope. I've reproduced all the steps above and didn't get it working somehow, as we can see in the picture.

Comment: And you're sure the username (blocked out of the image) has access rights to the repository in question? This would be time to get GitHub support involved. Although you might do one other thing first, which is to run `GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch` to observe the ssh command that Git runs (if you're on Windows, there's a mismatch between Git—which comes with an ssh client—and Windows itself, which comes with an ssh client).

Comment: @torek yes, like I said above, the user (me) does have all the access rights to the repository. I might as well call the GitHub support, I was just wondering whether I forgot something, as I've done it successfully in the past.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but my understanding is that *old* Windows ssh clients don't work with Git, while *new* Windows ssh clients do work with Git. Meanwhile the included-with-Git ssh client uses *different files* (not `~/.ssh/*`) so as to not interfere with the included-with-Windows ssh client.

Comment: If this is the problem, and your provided-with-Windows ssh works fine, just point your Git at the Windows ssh client using the `core.sshCommand` setting and/or path (again, since I don't use Windows, I don't have specific instructions here).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you don't have an environment variable `GIT_SSH`
- your `%PATH%` references `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` first

Make sure that:

- your remote origin URL is `git@github.com:me/myRepo`
- you have a `%USERNAME%\.ssh\config` file which set a the right private key file path, assuming it is not the default one (`id_rsa`).

That config file would be (again, only if the private key is nont the default one):

```
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile C:\path\to\private\key\file
```